# How to change position of a specfic <td> element inside a HTML table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

So, I have this table in which I need to place the td that contains the profile info further to the right as following:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahg94.png)

this is my HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
           <td>
                <asp:Label ID="****" runat="server" CssClass="FieldLabelRqrd" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="***" runat="server" Text="ID=****"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td colspan="4">
                <div id="cssProfile">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProfile" runat="server" Text="Profile:" CssClass="lblProfile"></asp:Label>                         
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlGoProfile" runat="server" ForeColor="blue" Target="_blank" CssClass="hlGoProfile" Text="Go"></asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
```

I tried colspan and rowspan but this does no work and here's the CSS

```
#cssProfile{    
    display:flex;
    justify-content: start-flex;}

.lblProfile{    
margin-left: auto;}

.hlGoProfile{   
margin-left: auto;}
```

Comment: Give your table the css `table-layout: fixed;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your table 100% width and add `text-align: right` to the cell in question.

BTW, you could remove that `colspan`, if you don't need it for any other purpose.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssProfile {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="****" runat="server" CssClass="FieldLabelRqrd" Text="Name">A</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="***" runat="server" Text="ID=****">B</asp:Label>
    </td>

    <td colspan="4">
      <div id="cssProfile">
        <asp:Label ID="lblProfile" runat="server" Text="Profile:" CssClass="lblProfile">C</asp:Label>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlGoProfile" runat="server" ForeColor="blue" Target="_blank" CssClass="hlGoProfile" Text="Go">D</asp:HyperLink>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! In the same example you posted, how would you to make the B label placed right next to the A label? I tired the text-align: left; on it but didn't work.

Comment: either `text-align: right `for the first label, or apply a (very small) `width` to the `td` that contains A